# Chrome 72 disabling the manage passwords dialog when you click on a textbox

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

I tried autocomplete= off, false.

autofill= off, false.

Both on the html element level and form level.

I tried changing the name of the textbox to something random like zxccvcvb.

I tried adding a hidden element with the same name or an empty image before the textbox.

I was able to stop autofilling by adding readonly attribute and removing it on onfocus event and it worked fine but I still get that manage password dialog when I click on the textbox.

There are many textboxes on my page and this happens only with 2 of them.
Any more ideas that I can try?

And we can't ask clients to turn off their autocomplete from Chrome settings.
Thanks.